# Can you add archive file directly to XCode Organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a friend bake an archive for me and I'd like to submit it to itunesconnect now.  Is there any way to add this archive to XCode's organizer or must I bake my own with the workspace file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the apploader.

Answer (score 15):

Double clicking on Archive would add it to organizer!
I have tried dragging into organizer but it doesn't work for XCode 9.0

Comment: It works if you drag it onto the dock Xcode icon, but not dragging onto the organiser window.

Answer (score 10):

Just drag the `.xcarchive` in Xcode and it will be added to the Xcode Organizer.