# How can you manually add an archive to Xcode 8's organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an archive built by a bot and want to provision it for ad-hoc deployment and so want to get it into Xcode's organizer window in order to select the Export button and provision it accordingly.

Dragging and dropping directly in the organizer doesn't work (says this can be done in unaccepted answer here [Can you add archive file directly to XCode Organizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885206/can-you-add-archive-file-directly-to-xcode-organizer))

I placed it in /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archies but it still didn't show up in the organizer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place it in the correct directory. Xcode archives are sorted by date, which you need to include in the path:

`/Users/XX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-05-18/Archive.xcarchive`

You may need to restart Xcode after modifying the archives directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to automatically move and show in the organizer

[image]